# Output Buffer Issue with Single Post View

Tags: posts, templates

I created the following function that I am using to load single post views:

```
// Post
function basey_single_post() {

    global $post;
    ob_start();

    echo apply_filters('basey_page_title_news', __('<h1>News</h1>','basey')); ?>
    <?php basey_post_before(); ?>
    <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <?php basey_post_inside_before(); ?>
            <header>
                <?php echo apply_filters('basey_post_title', '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>'); ?>
                <?php basey_entry_meta($post->ID); ?>
                <div class="taxonomy">
                    <?php echo __('Posted in ','basey'); the_category(', '); ?>
                </div>
                <?php $tag = get_the_tags(); if (!$tag) { } else { ?><div class="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></div><?php } ?>
                <div class="commentLinks"><?php comments_popup_link( __( ' 0 Comments', 'blank' ), __( ' 1 Comment', 'blank' ), __( ' % Comments', 'blank' ), 'comments-link', __('Comments closed', 'blank')); ?> <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>| <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#respond" title="<?php echo __('Add a Comment','basey'); ?>"><?php echo __('Add a Comment','basey'); ?></a><?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<nav class="pagination"><p>' . __('Pages:', 'basey'), 'after' => '</p></nav>' )); ?>
            </footer>
        <?php basey_post_inside_after(); ?>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
    </article>
    <?php basey_post_after();

    $display = apply_filters('basey_single_post_view',ob_get_clean());
    return $display;
}
```

and am then overriding it when needed like so:

```
// Post
function basey_single_post_override() {

    global $post;
    ob_start();

    echo 'TEST ADDITION';

    echo apply_filters('basey_page_title_news', __('<h1>News</h1>','basey')); ?>
    <?php basey_post_before(); ?>
    <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <?php basey_post_inside_before(); ?>
            <header>
                <?php echo apply_filters('basey_post_title', '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>'); ?>
                <?php basey_entry_meta($post->ID); ?>
                <div class="taxonomy">
                    <?php echo __('Posted in ','basey'); the_category(', '); ?>
                </div>
                <?php $tag = get_the_tags(); if (!$tag) { } else { ?><div class="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></div><?php } ?>
                <div class="commentLinks"><?php comments_popup_link( __( ' 0 Comments', 'blank' ), __( ' 1 Comment', 'blank' ), __( ' % Comments', 'blank' ), 'comments-link', __('Comments closed', 'blank')); ?> <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>| <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#respond" title="<?php echo __('Add a Comment','basey'); ?>"><?php echo __('Add a Comment','basey'); ?></a><?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<nav class="pagination"><p>' . __('Pages:', 'basey'), 'after' => '</p></nav>' )); ?>
            </footer>
        <?php basey_post_inside_after(); ?>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
    </article>
    <?php basey_post_after();

    $display = ob_get_clean();
    return $display;
}
add_filter('basey_single_post_view','basey_single_post_override');
```

Getting this error though: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare basey_comment() (previously declared in /home/usr/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/basey/comments.php:1) in /home/usr/public_html/dev/wp-content/themes/basey/comments.php on line 26` which looks like:

```
<?php function basey_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?>>
        <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
            <header class="comment-author vcard">
                <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='32'); ?>
        <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite>', 'basey'), get_comment_author_link()); ?>
        <time datetime="<?php echo comment_date('c'); ?>"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID)); ?>"><?php printf(__('%1$s', 'basey'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()); ?></a></time>
        <?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)', 'basey'), '', ''); ?>
            </header>

      <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-block fade in">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
          <p><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'basey'); ?></p>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>

            <section class="comment">
                <?php comment_text() ?>
            </section>

      <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))); ?>

        </article>
<?php } ?>

<?php if (post_password_required()) { ?>
    <section id="comments">
    <div class="alert alert-block fade in">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <p><?php _e('This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.', 'basey'); ?></p>
    </div>
  </section><!-- /#comments -->
    <?php
        return;
} ?>

<?php if (have_comments()) { ?>
    <section id="comments">
    <h3><?php printf(_n('One Response to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s Responses to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'basey'), number_format_i18n(get_comments_number()), get_the_title()); ?></h3>

        <ol class="commentlist">
      <?php wp_list_comments(array('callback' => 'basey_comment')); ?>
        </ol>

    <?php if (get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option('page_comments')) { // are there comments to navigate through ?>
      <nav id="comments-nav" class="pager">
        <div class="previous"><?php previous_comments_link(__('&larr; Older comments', 'basey')); ?></div>
        <div class="next"><?php next_comments_link(__('Newer comments &rarr;', 'basey')); ?></div>
            </nav>

    <?php } // check for comment navigation ?>

    <?php if (!comments_open() && !is_page() && post_type_supports(get_post_type(), 'comments')) { ?>
      <p><?php _e('Comments are closed.', 'basey'); ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
  </section><!-- /#comments -->
<?php } ?>

<?php if (!have_comments() && !comments_open() && !is_page() && post_type_supports(get_post_type(), 'comments')) { ?>
    <section id="comments">
    <p><?php _e('Comments are closed.', 'basey'); ?></p>
  </section><!-- /#comments -->
<?php } ?>

<?php if (comments_open()) { ?>
<section id="respond">
  <h3><?php comment_form_title( __('Leave a Reply', 'basey'), __('Leave a Reply to %s', 'basey') ); ?></h3>
    <p class="cancel-comment-reply"><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></p>
    <?php if (get_option('comment_registration') && !is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
  <p><?php printf( __('You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.', 'basey'), wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ); ?></p>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
        <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    <p><?php printf(__('Logged in as <a href="%s/wp-admin/profile.php">%s</a>.', 'basey'), get_option('siteurl'), $user_identity); ?> <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php __('Log out of this account', 'basey'); ?>"><?php _e('Log out &raquo;', 'basey'); ?></a></p>
        <?php } else { ?>
      <label for="author"><?php _e('Name', 'basey'); if ($req) _e(' (required)', 'basey'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author); ?>" size="22" tabindex="1" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?>>
      <label for="email"><?php _e('Email (will not be published)', 'basey'); if ($req) _e(' (required)', 'basey'); ?></label>
            <input type="email" class="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author_email); ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?>>
      <label for="url"><?php _e('Website', 'basey'); ?></label>
            <input type="url" class="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo esc_attr($comment_author_url); ?>" size="22" tabindex="3">
        <?php } ?>
      <label for="comment"><?php _e('Comment', 'basey'); ?></label>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="input-xlarge" tabindex="4"></textarea>
        <input name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="<?php _e('Submit Comment', 'basey'); ?>">
        <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
        <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
    </form>
    <?php } // if registration required and not logged in ?>
  </section><!-- /#respond -->
<?php }
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated on this - at my whits end here. Thanks!

*EDIT:* This may be more of a question about correctly using the output buffer and/or WP filters effectively. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, that `comments.php` file is being included or required more than once. You can make sure that any call to that file is done with `include_once` or `require_once` to prevent that issue.

Otherwise, a safe workaround would be to wrap the file contents with:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'basey_comment' ) ) :
   # code goes here
endif;
```

which will then only "process" the file if the function hasn't yet been declared.